# Java XML UTF-8 inconsistency

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a problem converting a UTF-8 document correctly into HTML.

When the code is run inside a glassfish server on Solaris, it produces invalid results.

When run on my test environment on Windows, the results are valid.

Both environments are using Java 1.6.0_27

I am including the code for both - I don't see any relevant difference.

The output from the app server test is below (if the UTF-8 goes through this process):

```
<CityName>Ð Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ñ Ð¸Ð±Ð¸Ñ€Ñ Ðº</CityName>

<CityName>Ð&#157;Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ñ&#129;Ð¸Ð±Ð¸Ñ&#128;Ñ&#129;Ðº</CityName>
```

Note that the second has several entity encodings, whereas the first is pure UTF-8. The encodings are wrong.

First - the app server code (logger is a log4j Logger - it shows good results on test13, bad on test14):

```
logger.info("===test13:"+descr+req);

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory .newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(req)));

logger.info("===test14:"+XmlHelper.domToString(doc));
```

Then, the test code - "out" shows good data in both cases:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
String inmsg = TestRvcMessage.readUtfFile(fname);
inmsg = inmsg.trim();
out.println("INPUT:"+inmsg);

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(inmsg)));

out.println("OUTPUT:"+xmlHelper.domToString(doc);
```

Comment: Both `<CityName>`s look like garbage to me... It looks like one platform is just dealing with the garbage differently than the other. Isn't `<CityName>` supposed to be sensible text?

Comment: They look like garbage because I wasn't able to post Unicode into here. The good one actually contains cyrillic characters.

Comment: Well, it is hard to tell how the problem is being introduced if you don't post what you have accurately.